# Code block formatting and validation is broken

Tags: bug, code-formatting

I am trying to edit code block in this answer - [RxJS Merge Observable in Callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46061883/rxjs-merge-observable-in-callback/46062035#46062035)

After my changes, the code block is formatted with 4 spaces, but validator says it's not: 
[image]

Also when I press <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> it remove or add 4 spaces instead of formatting:
[image]

Because of this, I can't save my changes. Am I doing something wrong or this validator is broken?

**UPD 1**

my browser console is clear, there are no warnings and no errors

- Tried to edit in Chrome Incognito window - got the same error
- Opened Safari which I never used - got the same error

**UPD 2**

Just asked my friend with ~4K rep to edit this - he got no errors. But when he opened it in Incognito browser tab - got the same error.

So is this a bug or a "privilege". If the second then there is a problem with the error message (it is incorrect)?

Comment: Hmm.  [I was able to apply a edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46062035/3).  Can you post the block bloxk you wanted it to be so we can see that?

Comment: Posted with your [code in the image](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/46062035/5) and it seemed to work fine?

Comment: @George just opened your revision and got the same error - https://i.imgur.com/hhzJ9Xy.png

Comment: Makes me wonder if it is something to do with it being a suggested edit.  Let me try and find another person with less than 2K rep.

Comment: Well, just had <2K user check and they were able to post an edit.  Not sure what could be the issue.

Comment: @NathanOliver just updated my question. Seems like you were right, this is somehow related to reputation. To be sure, could you please test this in Incognito tab or for a user with less than 1k rep?

Comment: I would hope it's a bug and not a privilege, allowing 2k+ users to make bad edits doesn't seem like a great privilege :)

Comment: It's a bug. I'm pretty sure I've seen edits to code from anonymous users before.

Comment: @NathanOliver Out of curiosity, will the answer go back to being non-wiki after this is resolved? Seems a shame that the answerer can't get any rep from their post due to an editing bug.

Comment: @BSMP The OP of the question and the answerer are not the same person. The answerer made the answer a CW so I don't think it will be reverted.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, I can definitely reproduce this as an anonymous user trying to suggest an edit. I get the same error message about there being code that isn't properly formatted as code.

It has nothing to do with the *actual* code block, and removing that entirely still doesn't fix the problem. The weird tilde character in the links isn't the source of the confusion, either. Nor were there any hidden characters lurking in there, contrary to my initial suspicions.

I narrowed the problem down to the blockquote. If you add a space after the `>` the first two places where it appears, then the error is avoided. In other words:

```
> create converts an onSubscription function to an actual Observable. Whenever someone subscribes to that Observable, the function will be called with an Observer instance as a first and only parameter
>
```

If you just add a space after the *first* `>`, that isn't enough; the edit still gets rejected.

But it doesn't *have* to be the second `>` (the one on a blank line). A space after the `>` on the third line (the second paragraph of text) is sufficient. Nor does it have to be the *first* `>`; a space after *any two* of the `>` characters seems to be enough.

Capitalizing the "c" in "create" doesn't have any effect. Apparently you need spaces. This is weird, because I don't remember that ever being a problem before. The markdown spec certainly doesn't call for whitespace here.

There is almost certainly a bug in the heuristic that detects "code".

(Said heuristic originated from [this Software Engineering question, asked by Jeff Atwood](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/87611/simple-method-for-reliably-detecting-code-in-text), but the actual implementation used by the Stack Overflow engine is not public, as far as I know.)

Comment: Is this a community wiki to indicate that this is additional info rather than a response to the bug report?

Comment: That, and because anyone else who decides to investigate this or has further information should feel free to update. @andras

Comment: @CodyGray do you have any idea why this error does not affect people with >1k rep?

Comment: My guess would be that the quality filter is not enforced as rigorously for established users, but I don't know for certain. @Oles